# how to code an ip tracer program in c?

Tags: ip, trace

i would like to code an ip tracer program in c , but i am not able to get a head start in it . Any e book , links or sample code would be of much needed help !!

Comment: Do you mean some utility like traceroute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of examples on [this site](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/winsock.html) for how to implement this sort of thing in **c**

Answer (score 0):

you will send icmp (ping) to the address, each time you extend the ttl (time to live) by 1 - and that's how you get the trace.

here some library that helps you use ping in c#

http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=4

Comment: if you want to get the names of the ip's on the way.. you should use other libraries to make rdns calls...